# Browser close on Paypal site

Tags: php, asp.net, content-management-system, paypal

how to check if a customer navigate to paypal site.  and if he close the browser and do not return back to the main site. then i have to do my code at this point.. if any idea.

and is it possible to pass my text to paypal site to show warning not to close the page etc et

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Paypal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) functionality to process a payment even if the user closes the browser down before they are redirected back to your site.

It's not clear from your question tags if you need a php or an asp.net solution, but the article below provides an excellent breakdown on how to integrate PayPal with a .net web-site -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that is to use Paypal's [IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

Paypal will post to your IPN script to inform you that a transaction has been affected. This is done server-to-server, so it is more reliable than waiting for the user's browser to return to your site.